# How can I remove elements from prepend() by click close button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an interface where images is being showed by .prepend() method, I am trying to **remove images one by one by click on close button and also remove all the images by one click on a button**, but I have no idea how to do ?

Here is **image list interface below, 3 images show as of now** How can I attach close button and remove images individual and also on 1 click.

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="imageList">
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
 //Images are stored in this array as base64
  var imagesBase64 = [];

// add images in the array ImagesBase64
function addToDownload() {  
   imagesBase64.push(dataURL); 
   appendImageToList(dataURL);
}

 const imageList = document.getElementById("imageList");

 function appendImageToList(image) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = image;
    imageList.prepend(img);
 }
```

Comment: "*I am trying to remove images one by one by click on close button and also remove all the images by one click on a button*" - you forgot to show those buttons in your HTML; where are they?

Comment: i didn't have any button as of now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I crafted a demo that does more or less what you asked (but using jQuery).
The page gets initialized with a list of pictures hardcoded in an array. Each picture gets appended in #imageList inside its own container and a little red box is added to trap the click event when you mean to remove the picture from the list. On top of that there's a button to remove all of them at once:

```js
//a list of img urls needed to feed the list of pictures with some
const images = ['https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg'];

//inits the imageList with pictures coming from images constant
//..so when the document is ready,
$(document).ready(() => {
  //for each url picture in the images constant
  images.forEach((o, i) => {
    //append a picture to imageList having that url
    appendImageToList(o);
  });
});

//appends an image to the list (where image is a picture url)
function appendImageToList(image) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = image;

  //the img will be enclosed in a container
  let container = $('<div>', {
    class: 'imgContainer'
  });
  container.append(img);

  //creates the close handle for this new picture and adds an event handler on its click event
  let closeHandle = $('<div>', {
    class: 'closeHandle'
  });
  //adds content x to the close handle
  closeHandle.append('<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>');

  closeHandle.click(() => {
    //when the button is clicked, remove this image from the list
    removeOneImageFromList($(event.target).closest('.imgContainer'));
  });
  container.append(closeHandle);

  //adds the container inside the imageList
  $('#imageList').prepend(container);
}

//removes all images from the list
function removeAllImages() {
  $('#imageList .imgContainer').remove();
}

//removes a specific image from the list
function removeOneImageFromList(imgParentElement) {
  $(imgParentElement).remove();
}
```

```css
/* rule to style every single img container */

#imageList .imgContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}


/* rule to style the close handle */

#imageList .closeHandle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="removeAllImages();">Remove all images</button>

<br><br>

<div id="imageList">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this recommendation, but while clicking on close button the element is removed from the container but `element is not removing from array by clicking on close button or remove all images` ?

Comment: The array images it's just a list of urls to populate the list of images when document has loaded. That array remains untouched. Every image you see on the document is created by appendImageToList() that doesn't feed any data array but just adds html elements to the DOM inside the container #imageList. When you click on the del button, the whole img container belonging to that picture is just removed from DOM and there's no reason to keep track of it anywhere else. The same happens with the remove all button. It just removes every html element .imgContainer included in the container #imageList

Comment: oh! thank a lot, but close button is not with `X`  only have red bg?

Comment: I added fontawesome and better styled the close button. Plus I added a comment to every single line. I think it's up to you now to better fit your specific expectations fine tuning that sample. I hope your request was fulfilled correctly and in that case I hope you'll accept my answer as valid

Comment: `removeAllImages()` this function is not calling in my html file I tried several times?

Comment: I don't get your point. You are asking a question? the function is defined and gets called by the click handler on the button "Remove all images". It works because it removes all the pictures inside the container. And you can call that function anytime or from anywhere. What's wrong?

Comment: I am calling this function `<button type="button" id="RemoveAll" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="removeAllImages()">Remove
                    all</button>
                  <br><br>
                  <div id="imageList">

                  </div>` like this but it says `removeAllImages()` function not defined, though I defined this in my js.file

Comment: this example you showed it's ok but you are doing some mess when importing the js that defines that function. Because the function is there and it's working in the snippet context. You could try to bring what you have in that js in a script tag inside the html page and start from there to address the issue. Look also in the console window when the page loads to see if there's any error showed.